# DC Stuck in Promotion Limbo

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard box that I was trying to set as a second domain controller, but ran into some problem and now it's stuck in promotion limbo.

I cannot promote it because I get the following error:

> Error determining whether the target server is already a domain
>   controller:  The domain controller promotion completed, but the server
>   is not advertising as a domain controller.

I am also unable to remove the AD DS role because DC needs to be demoted, which I also cannot do.  When trying to demote it, I get the following error:

> The operation failed because:
>
> DFS Replication: The target principal name is incorrect.
>
> "The target principal name is incorrect."

```
 /netdom query fsmo
```

sometimes shows the correct information and other times returns

> The target principal name is incorrect.
>
> The command failed to complete successfully.

I'm not a Windows Server expert, so this has me stumped.  Any advice would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks in advance.